# How to get X11 window ID of an browser window

Tags: javascript

I want to get X11 window Id of an browser window through JavaScript.
Also is there any ID associated with Div tag like Window X11 ID so that i can use it to display video stream in it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That sort of information is not going to be accessible to JavaScript in the browser, not in any kind of cross-browser compatible way and especially not if you want to do this from a web page vs. an intranet page vs. a local HTML file (you haven't said either way).

For video streaming, you'll need to use [HTML5 video](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/video.html) or fall back to some kind of video streaming plug-in (most sites Flash for that).